# verify all elements in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has a handful of dropdowns.  I want to confirm all dropdowns have been selected before form submit.  The id's of the elements are variable so i cant use them as a selector, so i put all the elements in the verify class.  So now i need to iterate through all elements that have the verify class and make sure they are not empty/undefined/null.  the number of elements is unknown as well.  I am guessing I would map or use each on some level, I just don't know where to begin.

```
 $('.verify').change(function()
 {
    //iterate through each item with verify class..


   if (//All items are selected)
   {

       $(":button:contains('Complete')").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass('ui-state-disabled' );
   }

 });
```

html:

```
<td class='dialog'>
         <select id='someVariable' class='verify'>
              <option value=''></option>
              <option value='1'>1</option>
              <option value='2'>2</option>
              <option value='3'>3</option>   
         </select>
</td>
<td class='dialog'>
         <select id='someOtherVariable' class='verify'>
              <option value=''></option>
              <option value='a'>a</option>
              <option value='b'>b</option>
              <option value='c'>c</option>   
         </select>
</td>
```

Comment: How are you submitting a form? A button click?  If so, you can iterate through all select elements to check if they have a value selected and then submit...

Answer (score 0):

First select the elements which are having `selected options` in it. and compare its `length` with the overall count of `select elements`. If counts are same, All elements have been selected.

Try,

```
var $varifies = $('.verify').change(function () {

  var xSelectedElems = $('.verify').filter(function () {
      return $(this).find('option:selected').val() != '';
  }).length;

  var xTotalElems = $('.verify').length;

  $(":button:contains('Complete')").prop("disabled", (xTotalElems != xSelectedElems));

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kF7Uw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $varifies = $('.verify').change(function () {
    //iterate through each item with verify class..

    var invalid = $varifies.filter(function () {
        return !$(this).val();
    }).length;
    $(":button:contains('Complete')").prop("disabled", invalid);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kF7Uw/)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest `$('.verify').not('[value!=""]').length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You might be over complicating it a little. On submit, loop over each `select.verify` element and check its value propery:

```
$($(".verify:first")[0].form).submit(function(event) {
    var valid = true, $form = $(this);

    $form.find(".verify").each(function() {
        if (/^\s*$/.test(this.value)) {
            valid = false;
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-invalid");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-invalid");
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $form
            .find(":button:contains('Complete')")
            .removeAttr("disabled")
            .removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```